# How to iterate PriorityBlockingQueue in order

Tags: java

I have a [`PriorityBlockingQueue<Shirts>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html) that uses a FIFO (first in first out) comparator in addition to other custom conditions.  While obeying the priority, I need to pull out only the Green shirts.  I understand the objective with a Queue is that they are intended for items to be "taken off of the top".  The `iterator()` doesn't obey the order, so I can't use that.  Should I be using a different queue altogether?  How can I iterate over these items.

Comment: The documentation you linked to mentions `Arrays.sort(pq.toArray())`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PriorityQueue.iterator() doesn't obey the order but retrieval operations poll, remove, peek, and element access the element at the head of the queue. So, taking into consideration that PriorityBlockingQueue cannot have null elements, you can iterate the elements in order this way

```
PriorityBlockingQueue<Shirts> q = ...
for (Shirts shirts; (shirts = q.poll()) != null; ) {
    ...      
}
```

Another way

```
     Shirts[] a = q.toArray(new Shirts[q.size()]);
     Arrays.sort(a);
```

now you can iterate in both direction

Comment: Your answer helped me come to the conclusion that iterating through the `PriorityBlockingQueue` is not the ideal solution for my situation.  What I really should be doing is maintaining separate `PriorityBlockingQueue`s for each type of product, since their priority is based on the type as well...

Answer (score -1):

Taking a look at the javadoc, you should be able to use the "take" method.

> public E take()
>          throws InterruptedException
>   Description copied from interface: BlockingQueue
>   Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, waiting if necessary until an element becomes available.

Just throw a for loop around the queue and voila! You can iterate with no problems.  :)

**Assuming the queue is strictly FIFO**

You can then use "put" to put the item back into the queue if it is not the green shirt

> public void put(E e)
>   Inserts the specified element into this priority queue. As the queue is unbounded, this method will never block.

This way the non-green shirts will still be in the queue in order (once the loop is finished).

**The way you have it setup**

Since you are using a PriorityBlockingQueue, putting the objects right back in the queue could eventually lead to the same item being pulled off the queue each time around the loop. You would need to create a new queue to put the item back into once it is checked to see if it is a green shirt.

**Example code**

PriorityBlockingQueue queue = new PriorityBlockingQueue();
        PriorityBlockingQueue backupqueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue();

```
    queue.put("A");
    queue.put("B");
    queue.put("C");
    queue.put("D");

    List<String> saveList = new ArrayList<String>();
    int initialSize = queue.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < initialSize; i++){
        String element = queue.take();
        if(element.equals("C")){
            saveList.add(element);
        } else {
            backupqueue.put(element);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Taking things out and putting them back in would lead to a lot of comparators being run.  That sounds expensive.

Comment: You have to defer putting them back until you had finished iterating, otherwise you will iterate forever. It would be a lot simpler to just copy the queue and then remove from the copy.

Comment: You should only be using the comparator once, whenever you remove it from the queue. Putting it back in the queue should not run a comparator, since you have already made sure it is not a green shirt.

Comment: @EJP As long as your for loop is setup to only iterate over the initial number of items in the queue, it wouldn't loop forever.

Comment: You will just keep reading the first item you read. This won't work. Try it.

Comment: Ah, interesting... My whole idea of queues has just been blown away. The way I have always understood them, putting an object adds it to the end of a queue, especially with FIFO. Have a bunch of research to do on this now...

Comment: So from what I am understanding, a standard PriorityBlockingQueue would NOT do FIFO. It is based on priority (well named I believe), which uses a comparator to determine priority. If a pure FIFO queue was used what I posted _would_ work. Rereading the question, OP states he is using a FIFO comparator (which is what I was basing everything on) but also "other custom conditions" (which would cause what I posted to not work since it is not pure FIFO). So in this case, it would be better to copy to another queue and not attempt to put the items back on the same queue.

Comment: In my case, I have a comparator that first orders by priority (1-5), and then uses FIFO to break those ties.

Comment: So suppose Red shirts are priority 1 (highest) and you only have one of them. Putting it back on the queue after checking to see if it was a Green shirt would result in it being pulled right back off in the next loop. So you would need to push it into another queue.

Comment: A PriorityQueue isn't a FIFO. It's a priority queue. Think about it.